# Deep Linking in Facebook iOS won't even open my native application

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

I'm trying to integrate Facebook Share into my App. For that, I'm following [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-games/feed/).
I can share something in Facebook, but I can't seem to make deep linking working. If I clicked in my share link in my wall, it won't open my native apps but it always open another tab in safari and open the link.
In the Apps detail Page in Facebook Apps, I've already checked **Enable Deep Linking**. But, because the apps isn't submitted to the app store yet, I left the iPhone App Store Id and iPad App Store Id to 0.
What is that I miss?

Comment: Did you happen to come across a solution ?